# Query Repo Using a String

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using Phoenix with Ecto to query a database for a single record by the primary key. All of the documentation/examples show the usage as in a Phoenix Controller:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  m = Repo.get(MyModel, id)

  ...
end
```

However, all params in Phoenix are strings, so this throws a `** (Ecto.InvalidModel) model App.MyModel failed validation when , field id had type string but type integer was expected`. I have been working around this in my controllers by doing something like:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
   m = String.to_integer(id) |> find_my_model_by_id

  ...
end

defp find_my_model_by_id(id) do
 Repo.get(MyModel, id)
end
```

The problem is I haven't seen anyone else doing this sort of type conversion. I'm worried I don't have Phoenix or Ecto set up correctly. Is there a Phoenix/Ecto convention I am missing that would automatically coerce my id argument for `Repo.get/2` to an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. In the upcoming Ecto version we want to add automatic casting for cases like this. But for now, you need to cast it manually.

Comment: Has it been added since then? What is the advised pattern as of 2020 to do this?

Answer (score 0):

tried on Ecto 2.2.0, it still doesn't automatically cast a string to integer in my query

```
where: u.user_id == ^user_id,
```

Got error:

```
(ArgumentError) Postgrex expected an integer in -9223372036854775808..9223372036854775807, got "33133". Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert the value accordingly.
```